# USB to Serial: LoopBack Read-Write Programs

Tags: c, macos, usbserial

I am using BAFO bf-810 USB to Serial adapter with pl2303 drivers on Mac OS X. I am a beginner in the field and so have got the high level APIs from [here](https://github.com/Marzac/rs232) which is a cross-platform API.

I have two programs, one to write and one to read. This API does not have a inbuilt samples in the code. So I had to look at other's APIs to get a picture of what had to be done (like, comOpen, comWrite etc.). With the limited knowledge, I wrote the following little programs using the linked APIs.

**sendSerial.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "rs232.h"

extern int errno;

int main(){
    comEnumerate();

    if(!comOpen(1, 9600)) printf("Cannot open the port\n");

    while (1){
        char data[1024] = "Hello World";
        int ret = comWrite(1, data, 512);
        printf("%d\n", ret);
        if(ret>0){
            printf("Bytes transferred!\n");
        } else{
            printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.

**recSerial.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "rs232.h"

extern int errno;

int main(){
    comEnumerate();
    if(!comOpen(1, 9600)) printf("Cannot open the port\n");

    char read[1024] = "EMPTY";

    printf("\nNow reading data at %s...\n",comGetPortName(1));

    while (1){
        printf(".\n");
        if(comRead(1, read, 4)){
            printf("Data: %s\n**\n", read);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The [source](https://github.com/Marzac/rs232) has a single C program and might help on what I might be missing.

**Question**

When sending data, the write returns the `Resource temporarily unavailable` error after the third iteration. *Why is this happening consistently?* When I restart the sender program when the receiver is running, the error starts off with the first iteration itself.

In any case, I am not able to read any data on the read side of the program. I understand that the RS232 is an async protocol, but I've read somewhere that the system has a buffer of around 4 Mb before the data gets overwritten. So the second question is, *do I have to manually handle the clock synchronisation?*

P.S.: For the loopback test, I have connected, Send-Recieve, RTS-CTS and DTR-DSR on the DB9 connector.

Comment: It may be waiting for the "carrier" (DCD). For loopback testing, it is usual to connect DTR to both DSR and DCD.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well, but to no avail. Also, I've tried other APIs including the python serial extension. That does not work as well. I'm running out of ways to do anymore about the situation. Is there a way to isolate the problem at least so that I can further inquire into it... For instance, pointing out the possible failures or mistakes could help.